# Spring security custom session timeout

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security with my spring mvc webapp and I am trying to implement a custom session expiry. My requirement is when the session expired I need to retreive the user for which the session expired and then grab something from their security contexxt and write it to the redirect url.

The problem I am facing is that on session timeout the security context is not the user for which the session has timed out. Instead the security context comes out as anonymous user.

How can I get org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter to pass the user for which the session has timed out into onInvalidSessionDetected(request, response);

Here is the method in SessionManagementFilter where I need to somehow get the user for which the session timeout is happening and pass it to invalidSessionStrategy. Or alternatively can I just grab that inside invalidSessionStrategy.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    if (request.getAttribute(FILTER_APPLIED) != null) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    request.setAttribute(FILTER_APPLIED, Boolean.TRUE);

    if (!securityContextRepository.containsContext(request)) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication != null && !authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication)) {
         // The user has been authenticated during the current request, so call the session strategy
            try {
                sessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(authentication, request, response);
            } catch (SessionAuthenticationException e) {
                // The session strategy can reject the authentication
                logger.debug("SessionAuthenticationStrategy rejected the authentication object", e);
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                failureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, e);

                return;
            }
            // Eagerly save the security context to make it available for any possible re-entrant
            // requests which may occur before the current request completes. SEC-1396.
            securityContextRepository.saveContext(SecurityContextHolder.getContext(), request, response);
        } else {
         // No security context or authentication present. Check for a session timeout
            if (request.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
                logger.debug("Requested session ID" + request.getRequestedSessionId() + " is invalid.");

                if (invalidSessionStrategy != null) {
                    invalidSessionStrategy.onInvalidSessionDetected(request, response);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

When I do Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication(); inside onInvalidSessionDetected I get an anonymous user which is not what I want.

thanks

Comment: I think what I am trying to do is not possible. I might have to create something like the remember me cookie

Comment: can you tell what information is needed from the security context, to pass in the redirect to the logout page?

Comment: Normally you could but after session expiry the session is removed from the session registry and the security context only has access to an anonymous context